# cannot add a jar to scala repl with the :cp command

Tags: scala, jar, classpath, read-eval-print-loop

If I issue:

```
$ scala -classpath poi-3.9/poi-3.9-20121203.jar 

scala> import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet
```

Everything works ok, but if instead I issue:

```
$ scala

scala> :cp poi-3.9/poi-3.9-20121203.jar
Added '/home/sas/tmp/poi/poi-3.9/poi-3.9-20121203.jar'.  Your new classpath is:
".:/home/sas/tmp/poi/poi-3.9/poi-3.9-20121203.jar"
Nothing to replay.

scala> import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet
<console>:7: error: object apache is not a member of package org
       import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet
                  ^
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: which version of Scala are you using?

Comment: Apparently that's a known issue. It doesn't work anymore with Scala 2.10+: [SI-6502](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6502).

Comment: using Scala code runner version 2.10.1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

Comment: I didn't see the problem with scala 2.11.0, although I used an absolute path.

Answer (score 5):

No one seems to mention this but the correct solution is using the [`:require` command](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4251):

```
scala> :require foo.jar
Added 'foo.jar' to classpath.
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this does not need an alternate repl or changing environment variables. Works just like :cp, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get jar files imported, in this case by default, is to add links in $SCALA_HOME/lib to the jar files of interest. Then every time you enter REPL, such linked jars will be uploaded.

For instance, for `poi-3.9-20121203.jar`, consider

```
(cd $SCALA_HOME/lib && ln -s full_path_to_poi_jar/poi-3.9-20121203.jar)
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this is a known issue. You could use an alternative REPL implementation such as [Ammonite](https://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL).